# tvOS - View throwing warning (UIVisualEffect)

Tags: tvos

I am building an app for Apple TV and I added a textfield with IBAction.
I am getting this warning in the console:

> 2015-09-10 13:37:44.650 testTv[1199:182117] ; layer = >'s window is not
>   equal to 's view's window!
>
> 2015-09-10 13:37:54.347 testTv[1199:182117]  is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause
>   the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.1

Anyone knows why this warning appears?

Comment: Are you attempting to animate a blur view?

Comment: to animate the UIVisualEffect, change the UIColor on the background. not the alpha.